# if $A,B,C$ are real numbers such that ,${ A }^{ 2 }+{ B }^{ 2 }+{ C }^{ 2 } = 1 $ and $A+B+C = 0 $ find the maximum value of $(ABC )^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

$$A,B,C$$ are real numbers such that ,$${ A }^{ 2 }+{ B }^{ 2 }+{ C }^{ 2 } = 1 $$ and $$A+B+C = 0 $$   find the maximum value of ${ (ABC) }^{ 2 }$

I don't know how can I start to solve this question . I hope you can help me in solving it or even giving me hints .

Comment: nice question+1

Comment: I wonder if the name is just a coincidence...

Comment: @Daniel that's not a coincidence

Comment: .........      I'm as you

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider $(A+B+C)^2$, and look up the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: That will be lower bound